# How Can I know how much data is written to which executer during Shuffle-write in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I ran a simple wordcount and trying to understand exactly how spark processed the data there are 3 executers below , **I want to know more about shuffle , like 
for first executer which wrote 16.2 KB of data how much did it write to each executer** ? Also shuffle write is only to disk or disk + memory ?

**Aggregated Metrics by Executor**

*Time   |Tasks| Failed|   Succeed|   Input/records |  Shuffle write/records*

```
1.4min   6    0        6        1536.0 MB/15571058    16.2 KB / 1638
1.4min   6    0        6        1536.0 MB/15571061    16.4 KB / 1638
1.5min   7    0        7        1682.5 MB/17056569    19.0 KB / 1911
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out how shuffle exactly works in spark.
Shuffle write -> Each executer will produce a local file **on disk** after the map stage
Shuffle Read  -> Cumulative data **FETCHED** by an executer from all other executers.